# Junit error in Eclipse

Tags: java, junit

```
package com.test;

public class Calculation {
     public static int add(int n1, int n2)
     {
           return n1 + n2;
     }

     public static int sub(int n1, int n2)
     {
           return n1 * n2;
     }
}
```

Above is my class and
below is my JUnit test class

```
package com.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class CalculationTest extends Calculation
{
     CalculationTest test = new CalculationTest();
     @Test

     public void testadd() 
     {
          assertEquals(9,Calculation.add(1,8));
     }
     public void testsub() 
     {
          assertEquals(12,Calculation.sub(15,3));
     }
}
```

Hello any help would be appreciated i'm currently trying to get an error on my subtest because it's wrong in my class, however the error i'm currently getting is on Line 9 of my junit which is why I can't figure why it's causing an error.

> CalculationTest test = new CalculationTest();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 9, `CalculationTest test = new CalculationTest();`, causes the default constructor to be called on creation of a new `CalculationTest` instance.  The code declares that a `CalculationTest` instance contains a `CalculationTest` instance.  This is likely to recurse infinitely, and in fact does do so on my computer, resulting in the JVM throwing a `StackOverflowError`.

The `test` member of `CalculationTest` is not used and does not appear to be needed - perhaps consider simply removing that line then addressing the other issues raised in other answers and comments of this question?

Comment: Yes, you're correct and thank you for explaining it to me

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for confirming that the answer was helpful to you. If this answer answers your question and is useful to you could you please, as per site convention, upvote and accept the answer I provided? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your sub method has an error:

```
public static int sub(int n1, int n2) {
       return n1 - n2;
 }
```

Secondly I would advise you to dispose of static methods. Non static methods are better when testing, overwriting. So if you have a chance to make them non-static I would encourage you do change them.

So your test sould look like thos:

```
public class CalculationTest {

 @Test
 public void testAdd() 
 {
      assertEquals(9,Calculation.add(1,8));
 }
 @Test
 public void testSub() 
 {
      assertEquals(12,Calculation.sub(15,3));
 }
}
```

Comment: I've checked by putting that in the code to see if that was the error, That's the error i'm trying to get i want that part of it to be wrong.
But when i run it in j unit and get the red bar, i check the error and it's on line 9 of the test.

Comment: You are missing @Test on second method.

Comment: Yes i am, thankyou & Yes you're right it works if it looks like that, thankyou